# Detail in a proof about energy minimizing harmonic maps

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

Let $u\in H^1(B_1;S^k)$, where
$$B_1:= \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lvert x\rvert<1\}\\
S^k:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}: \lvert x\rvert=1\}.
$$
Suppose $u$ is a minimizer for the Dirichlet energy functional
$$
I[u]:=\int_{B_1}\lvert Dw\rvert^2\mathrm{d}x
$$
We denote $\bar{u}:=\frac{1}{|{B_1}|}\int_{B_1}u\mathrm{d}x$.
Let $\rho\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ such that

$$
\int\limits_{\partial B_\rho}|u-\bar{u}|^2\mathrm{d}x\le 3\int\limits_{B_1}|u-\bar{u}|^2\mathrm{d}x
$$

$$
\int\limits_{\partial B_{\rho}}|Du|^2\mathrm{d}x\le 3\int\limits_{B_1}|Du|^2\mathrm{d}x.
$$

Let $v:B_{\rho}\to\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta v=0\quad\text{in}\;\, B_\rho \\
v=u\quad\text{on}\;\,\partial B_\rho
\end{cases}.
$$
I have to prove that
$$
\int\limits_{B_\rho}|Dv|^2\mathrm{d}x\le c(n)(\int\limits_{\partial B_{\rho}}|D_Tu|^2\mathrm{d}x\int\limits_{\partial B_{\rho}}|u-\bar{u}|^2\mathrm{d}x)^{1/2}
$$
where $D_Tu$ is the tangential derivative of $u$.

Comment: I think it's an application of Green formula.

Comment: But I can't realize that: $$\int_{\partial B_\rho}|u|^2\le c\int_{\partial B_\rho}|u-\bar{u}|^2 $$